# Android - Проблемы с HTTPpost

Tags: http, android, java

Пытаюсь отправить данные на сайт (онлайн игра) через HTTPPost.
Но в ответ получаю вот это:

```
<html> qrator http 502 - application unreachable </html>
```

Как это исправить?

*Сообщение "QRATOR HTTP 502" означает, что Web-сервер клиента недоступен извне (как правило, в связи с проблемами в выбранном клиентом хостинг-центре)*

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема на стороне сервера, то Вы никак не исправите ситуацию на стороне клиента.